# Changes to grub and grub.cfg are ignored

Tags: grub2, lubuntu

I am a completely new to Linux, so this is probably something simple that I'm missing but I have exhausted all search options and nothing has worked.

I did a clean install of Kodibuntu and updated (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade). So the machine is now running Lubuntu 14.04 up to date as of 2016-08-17.
The issue I am having is with the Lubuntu shell. I am unable to get the grub at startup to disappear. It has been there since installation and is persistent after two clean installs. The grub being there is an issue as the machine is controlled via touchscreen and remote, so no option to select anything in the grub, and the grub never times out.

When I boot I see the following options without a timeout counter or anything:

```
[  ] Ubuntu
[  ] Advanced options for Ubuntu
[  ] Memory test (memtest86x)
[  ] Memory test (memtest86x, serial console 11520)
```

The content of "grub":

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=1
```

The content of "grub.cfg":

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  801c66b8-e7e0-4b85-b050-aa5b1104ee11
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 801c66b8-e7e0-4b85-b050-aa5b1104ee11
fi
    font="/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
 if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=1
 else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=countdown
    set timeout=1
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 1 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
 fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
set linux_gfx_mode=keep
export linux_gfx_mode

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

I followed several 'solutions' I found online, but nothing seems to work. I changed the grub file, moved several files (with number 30) from /etc/grub.d and ran "sudo update-grub" and saw "grub.cfg" update to what you see above. I would expect there to be no options like memtest in the grub anymore, but yet they are still appearing.

Also, setting "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false" and "GRUB_TIMEOUT=1" has no effect.

Finally I tried grub-customizer with no avail. Nothing I do to change grub or grub.cfg seems to have any effect.

Does anybody know how I could get the grub to timeout (or better yet, not to come up at all)?

Comment: Seems that the grub was being forced somehow. Installing grub again `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` made it adhere to what is in grub.cfg

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It seems you have provided a solution to your question in the comments. Since you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the grub was being forced somehow.
Installing grub again made it adhere to what is in grub.cfg, but it did remove the splashscreen that was there before.

Installing again was done with:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```